# Programatically set AWS region with a profile

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I have multiple profiles defined both in `.aws/credentials` and `.aws/config`

```
[profile dev]
region = us-east-1

[profile staging]
region = eu-west-1
```

Using the NodeJS AWS SDKv3 I can load credentials from my local config:

```js
const {S3Client} = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const {fromIni} = require('@aws-sdk/credential-providers');

new S3Client({
    credentials: fromIni({
        profile: 'dev'
    })
});
```

**How can I do the same for region?** (something akin to the following)

```js
const {S3Client} = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const {fromIni} = require('@aws-sdk/credential-providers');
const {fromIni: regionFromIni} = require('@aws-sdk/region-providers');

new S3Client({
    credentials: fromIni({
        profile: 'dev'
    }),
    region: regionFromIni({
        profile: 'dev'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fedonev pointed me to a solution that works:

```js
const {loadSharedConfigFiles} = require('@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader');

const sharedConfig = await loadSharedConfigFiles();
console.log(sharedConfig.configFile.dev?.region);
```